# Adding maven support to existing IntelliJ module is not available

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I just started an IntelliJ plugin project, and after going a few steps, I realized that I am not managing dependencies with maven. Naturally I head over to the module in the project explorer, and `right click -> Add Framework Support`. But Maven is not listed! In fact, the only thing listed is Groovy. What could cause this, and how do I get maven back?

The maven plugin is enabled.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: I was just trying to do this on a IntelliJ 2020.1 project, and the framework did not show up for Maven, only Python was showing up. I even disabled the auto filter in the Facets tab in the Project Structure website.

Answer (score 10):

The above options might take some time to execute but there is a quick fix to this if you already have a pom.xml file present in the project.
Right click on the pom.xml file and you will see an option

**Add as Maven Project**

[image]

Comment: Many, many thanks.  Been trying to work with a pre-generated JMH project structure and this was the one solution that helped me figure out how to get IntelliJ to recognize anything.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458618/297331) is a brief answer how to get going with Gradle, but most questions remain unanswered.

### How to manage development life cycle of IntelliJ plugins with Maven

For a comprehensive read this post : http://labs.bsb.com/2013/11/how-to-manage-development-life-cycle-of-intellij-plugins-with-maven-2/

The post also includes a link to the source code on github.

#### Making your plugin project use maven in IntelliJ

This is probably not what you are struggling with, but I include it just in case. Supposing you have already started a new plugin project you have two options:

1. Right-click on the project name in the project explorer and choose `New > Module`
2. Create a `pom.xml` in the project root, then right-click on it and choose `Add as Maven Project`

hth

Comment: I haven't actually gotten this far in my playing around with plugins, I need to include some of this in my current project.

Answer (score 6):

First, make sure you have enabled maven plugin in

File -> Settings -> Plugins and add search the maven plugin and activate

Restart the IntelliJ.

Go and check the tool window to make it visible

go to View -> Tool Windows > Maven Projects to open it.

Comment: File -> Settings -> Plugins and add search the maven plugin and activate
There is no such menu option,  Intellij File -> menu has no Settings.
Maybe you are thinking of Eclipse?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understood, you have to mark your folder with pom.xml as Maven module.

In order for the project to become Maven:

1. Go to - File -> Project Structure (or Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S)-> Modules.
   In the middle, you must remove the existing module.
2. Then in the same place of window click on the plus -> Import module -> Select the 
   required folder with pom.xml -> Import module from external module -> Maven -> Next -> 
   Finish
3. You may need to restart your IntelijIdea. Better just in case to restart it.
4. After restarting it, it should be appear a pop-up window in the lower right corner - Import maven module -> Click on it.
   After that, the folder for module and pom.xml should be displayed as Maven.

P. S. Also check before these steps, that you have Maven support for your IntelijIdea.

Comment: This worked for me. After deleting and importing module, Maven was visible.

Answer (score 1):

To get the option in the right hand of intellij you have to follow two step given below -

1. Right click on Pom.xml
2. Click on "add as Maven Project"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it being **root** as intelliJ launcher... not the best solution but seems a workaround.
So the best solution I found yet instead of digging into filesystem to see where there is a permissions problem was to change the owner to my user

`sudo chown -R myUsername:myUsergroup /opt/becauseIInstalledItHere/idea-IC-version`