# How to enable gradle in an IntelliJ-plugin project

Tags: gradle, intellij-plugin

When you create an IntelliJ 13 plugin project you can't also choose to make it a Gradle project. How do you start a plugin development project that is backed by Gradle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of IntelliJ, 13.1.2, only supports Gradle-integration up to version 1.10. Configure this version of Gradle as your project's gradle home.

Now start by creating a `build.gradle` file in your project root.

If you try to run the gradle build in IntelliJ now you will get the message: *"Error running build: Module 'your-plugin' is not backed by gradle"*. Close and reopen your project.

You will now have the option to import your project.

Viola!